# -webkit-border-radius:10px; is not working in safari

Tags: html, webkit, css

```
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
```

is not working in safari. I have used css for all browsers like this:

```
.nav {border:1px solid #e5e5e5;width:100px;height:32px;-moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;-webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;-khtml-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;behavior:url(../images/PIE.htc);border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;}
```

Anybody can help me?
Thanks
Tapas

Comment: try the official (CSS3 version) mark-up for border radius and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the version of Safari that you are using supports shorthand CSS3 for border radius values? Try setting them with

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius 
-webkit-border-top-right-radius 
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius 
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius
```

Alternatively you can have a look at using http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/ and this will eliminate your need to specify multiple browser prefixes.

Comment: Thank you very much Dan Prince, its working now fine. Thanks lot.

Comment: Than you Dan Prince, I was struggling with this one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with Safari 4.0.4 (and probably some others) that doesn't like border-radius shorthand. See [this post](http://csswizardry.com/2010/03/a-quick-note-on-border-radius/) from CSS Wizardry. You will have to define the webkit versions with the longhand markup:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius:8px 8px 0 0;
border-radius:8px 8px 0 0;
```

As suggested in Dan's answer.